# CSS, HTML - Need help to change the text of child element when input gets checked and also change the icon

Tags: html, css

The styling is almost complete, but I am still having one more problem. What the css does right now is, it changes the text and changes the icon but puts the icon on top of the text because the text gets changed using `position: absolute`.

How do I keep the icon in position?

```css
.an_radio input:checked+span+i:before {
  position: relative;
  content: "\f00c" !important;
}

.an_radio input:checked+span:before {
  content: "toegevoegd";
  visibility: visible;
}

.an_radio input:checked+span {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="radio-inline an_radio" style="display: inline-block;">
  <label class="top" style="min-width: 7px">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span>voeg toe</span>
    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean the position of the check must be the same as the cart?

Comment: just remove the position absolute on the span?

Comment: Note that the `<link>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Do it with few line of code https://stackoverflow.com/a/59947166/12434428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also play with `display: none` if you rearrange your `html`:

```css
#checkedText {
  display: none;
}

.an_radio input:checked~i:before {
  position: relative;
  content: "\f00c" !important;
}

.an_radio input:checked~#checkedText {
  display: inline;
}

.an_radio input:checked~#uncheckedText {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="radio-inline an_radio" style="display: inline-block;">
  <label class="top" style="min-width: 7px">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span id="uncheckedText">voeg toe</span>
    <span id="checkedText">toegevoegd</span>
    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: @Avion Not a problem ;) Can you please `upvote` my answer thanks ?

Comment: Done, I thought I had already done that but whatever. All good now :)

Answer (score 2):

Change Some HTML

```css
.an_radio input+span b {
  font-weight: normal
}

.an_radio input:checked+span b {
  display: none;
}

.an_radio input:checked+span:before {
  content: "toegevoegd";
  visibility: visible;
}

.an_radio input:checked+span i:before {
  content: "\f00c" !important;
  visibility: visible;
  position: relative;
}

.an_radio input:checked+span {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="radio-inline an_radio" style="display: inline-block;">
  <label class="top" style="min-width: 7px">
    <input type="checkbox" name="an_productfields_1[]" id="an_productfields_1_0" value="Basis servicepakket" class="Basis servicepakket" data-price="0" data-pricemain="0">
    <span>
      <b>voeg toe</b> <!-- Change Here -->
      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> <!-- Change Here -->
    </span>

  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this did the job!

Answer (score 1):

Why we write a complex code if we can do it with few lines of CSS.

```css
.an_radio input:checked+strong+i:before {  
  content: "\f00c" !important;
}
.an_radio input:checked+strong:after {
  content: "toegevoegd"; 
}
.an_radio input:checked+strong>span { 
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="radio-inline an_radio" style="display: inline-block;">
  <label class="top" style="min-width: 7px">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <strong> <span>abcd</span></strong>
    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: It adds spacing to the text, but it almost solved the problem.